# how to insert data in multiple tables at same time in mvc 4 razor using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Product collection1, Coin_Bar collection2, Jewellery collection3, Gift collection4, StockDetail collection5, ProductRating collection6)
        {
            //var vm=new ViewModel();
            //vm.Coin_Bars=entity.Coin_Bar();
            //vm.
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result1=entity.Products.Add(collection1);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            long ProductIds = result1.ProductId;

            collection2.ProductId = ProductIds;
            var result2 = entity.Coin_Bar.Add(collection2);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            collection3.ProductId = ProductIds;
            var result3 = entity.Jewelleries.Add(collection3);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            collection4.ProductId = ProductIds;
            var result4 = entity.Gifts.Add(collection4);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            collection5.ProductId = ProductIds;
            var result5 = entity.StockDetails.Add(collection5);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            collection6.ProductId = ProductIds;
            var result6 = entity.ProductRatings.Add(collection6);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

How to add view for all table fields in one view? Please help me..

Comment: View as in database view or MVC view?  Please expand on what you are looking to do...

Answer (score 0):

An MVC view can only work with a single model. As a result, you can't post back data for multiple different entity types as separate parameters like you're trying to do in the code you provided.

However, you *can* utilize a view model to encapsulate all of these so that you can work with each individually while still only passing one "model" back and forth in the view. For example:

```
public class CollectionViewModel
{
    public CollectionViewModel()
    {
        Product = new Product();
        Coin_Bar = new Coin_Bar();
        Jewellery = new Jewellery();
        StockDetail = new StockDetail();
        ProductRating = new ProductRating();
    }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Coin_Bar Coin_Bar { get; set; }
    public Jewellery Jewellery { get; set; }
    public Gift Gift { get; set; }
    public StockDetail StockDetail { get; set; }
    public ProductRating ProductRating { get; set; }
}
```

New this view model up in your get action and pass it to the view:

```
var model = new CollectionViewModel();
return View(model);
```

Then, in your view, you can create the fields for each like:

```
@model Namespace.To.CollectionViewModel

...

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Product.SomeProperty)
```

And finally, in you post action, you receive the view model:

```
public ActionResult Create(CollectionViewModel model)
```